# does silverlight support remoting?

Tags: .net, silverlight, remoting

Does silverlight support the remoting functionality of the .net framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to the security requirements of being sandboxed in the host web browser, binary serialization is not supported. So no, .NET Remoting is not supported. Thank goodness we have a fairly sufficient WCF implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Not implemented exactly like the full .NET framework, no.  But Silverlight supports Sockets if you need that level of communication.